# Editing CSPROJ for migrating to .NET Core from .NET Framework

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have class library collection in .NET Framework 4.6.2, will be migrating to .NET Core 2.0/3.0.
While migrating to core I will be doing doing changes(Changed `<PropertyGroup> <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework> </PropertyGroup>`) in csproj of newly created core application.
Will there be any performance effect like gain or loss?

Comment: you say "Changed `<PropertyGroup> <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework> </PropertyGroup>`" - is that changed *from*? or *to*? what is it now?

Answer (score 0):

The `TargetFramework` doesn't directly impact the performance; it changes the target framework. If you change it to `net462`, then it won't work on .NET Core - it would need to be `netstandard*` or `netcoreapp*` (for some numeric `*`) for that to work. Note that .NET Core has some significant performance improvements compared to .NET Framework (due to a combination of JIT improvements and just code improvements), but the bigger problem is just "it won't work" (i.e. you can't properly consume a `net462` library from .NET Core).

Note that multi-targeting is common if you want to use specific platform features when possible; for example:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net462;netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```

Note: if you aren't changing the dependencies or code based on the framework, you should instead just use:

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have created core application and I have changed the target framework to net462 and copied the code files from the framework library to core library application.
I have read some articles and blogs they are suggested me to change the CSPROJ.
Due to this will there be any cause in performance. Because am still pointing to .NET framework.

Comment: @SRINIVASREDDYVELPULA no, there should be no performance impact from simply changing to SDK-style csproj